# Can't update apps on iPhone 5S. Keeps prompting for password

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

Not able to update apps. Keeps prompting for password and despite resetting many times still no luck. I've reset but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone else ever used your device? Did you ever login as somebody else to download an application? Do you (or have you) ever had more than one Apple ID? Did you change email addresses and set up a new Apple ID instead of changing the email address on the old one? Apps will only update with the Apple ID that was used to purchase/acquire them. Most likely the ID you are putting in is not the ID that was used to originally acquire them.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iDevice to a computer, then remove the apps causing problems. Reinstall them then and all should be well.